# Servo motor too noisy

Tags: arduino, motor, servo

I’m currently using a Hitec HS-645MG servo to swing a piece of thick piano wire approximately 2ft long in a 180 degree arc. Servo being controlled via Arduino.

It needs to swing back and forth quickly.

I was able to get it to do the motion but the servo makes quite a bit of noise.

Any way to make it quiet? Perhaps I’m using the wrong component? Maybe there’s something else than a servo that doesn’t make as much noise?

Comment: Using plastic instead of metal internal gears would often give reduced noise.  This is often an option from servo manufacturers.

Comment: What do you mean by silent? Gear noise can be reduced, with quality gearsets.  Motor winding noise?  That can sometimes be moved out of the audible range, but eliminating it entirely is a challenge.  And as phrased, this is a pure shopping question, and will be closed.

Comment: the read/write head actuator from a hard drive is practically silent

Comment: If it has gears, it probably won't be so silent, and you tend to need gears for low RPM and high torque.. What is the application?

Comment: You'd need to far better define what you meant by "servo motor". You MAY mean a limited rotary motion device as commonly found in model and hobby use. That is NOT the traditional use of the term. Regardless, if you give your design spec and not a solution description we may be able to help.

Comment: @DKNguyen - RC hobby servos are geared due to the tiny motors, but many of the larger servomotors on industrial machinery are either direct drive, or perhaps use a relatively quiet toothed belt.  They aren't silent, but they don't have gear noise.  In fact ordinary gearing would not be suitable for many servomotor applications due to the backlash.

Comment: What is the maximum acceptable noise level? What wire gauge is 'thick', and how fast is 'quickly'?

Comment: Would Lord Mounts made of Neoprene for the servo motor reduce coupling of noise to the frame?  There is a significant  lack of details and replies to questions.

Answer (score 2):

Servo motors use current to force coils to create rotor torque from Magneto-motive force MMF.  They are "often"  called voice coils for the reason that the electro-mechanical motion sounds like a speaker. (unintentionally)

Generally, many devices have software options to reduce acceleration to reduce the frequency range of acoustic emissions.  This is a common feature on hard disk drives (HDDs).

Possible noise emitters:  Motor coil,magnet,gears,piano wire, motor mounts, lack of vibration isolators
 - There are micro harmonic motions and fundamental low frequency motion.
 - The harmonic motions give greater torque by the  gear ratio
 - The high current torque creates a vibration stress and strain with insufficient stiffness
Micromotion

First you must define a system with detailed specs on form , fit and function including environmental noise emissions with other methods to attenuate noise.

Beyond this there is no catalog of noise-free servos, only open ended system design requirements that demand custom R&D solutions.

### Generalized Solution

1. Test the servo for acoustic emissions.
2. Measure the level and determine the amount of suppression required to make it acceptable.  (design goal)
3. Test other performance parameters for time or frequency and highlight requirements

   - Identify what causes Piano wire to make acoustic vibrations from both natural resonance and exciter spectrum.
   - figure out how to attenuate exciter spectrum while minimizing loss of performance.
   - for example [image]
   - measure spectrum of noise and isolate root cause
   - determine if attenuation is possible by filtering servo current or slew rate or limit.
   - determine if structure is amplifying Q of the acoustic noise that can be improved by stronger motor or structural support or member (piano wire has very high Q)

### caveat

this is just off the cuff method of resolving acoustic servo noise with no problem data, at the time of this writing. (i.e test results and specs)

[image]

**Unless you define the problem with estimated  values as specs (dB)&(Hz)  and the acceptable results, the solution cannot be defined.**

Comment: Servo motors are not called voice coils

Comment: I should have added context Scott.  "many" Servo Engineers realize the effects and coin the term of servo motors as voice coils. just as electromagnetic servo controlled  vibratory exciters look like massive woofers.  Having been a servo engineer and worked with some of the best, I think  they would agree servo motors have acoustic emissions with different amounts.

Comment: Every voice coil I've seen is a linear actuator.

Comment: then you have no servo experience for the electromechanical units in your computers for the last 30 years  eg HDD voice coils  which is about when HDD linear voice coils became extinct.

Comment: Show me *one* reference where a model aircraft servo is call a voice coil.  We should not be promulgating wrong stuff.

Comment: sure H2Wtech    https://www.h2wtech.com/category/rotary-voicecoil-actuators#productInfo1

Comment: A servo amplifier is not what people are referring to when talking about model aircraft servos.

Comment: The DV is not mine, BTW

Comment: The servo consists of a driver, motor and feedback sensor, control system  etc . the **voice coil is the motor part** of the servo. it can be linear or rotary. Can you delete your incorrect statements. I can backup mine or delete them. TY for challenging me to backup my statements

Comment: Voice Coil Wikipedia entry: "A voice coil (consisting of a former, collar, and winding) is the coil of wire attached to the apex of a loudspeaker cone. It provides the motive force to the cone by the reaction of a magnetic field to the current passing through it. The term is also used for voice coil linear motors, such as those used to move the heads inside hard disk drives, which produce a larger force and move a longer distance but work on the same principle."

Comment: yes that's a very myopic definition consistent with technology in the early 80's (i.e. poor definition)  "Every voice coil I've seen is a linear actuator Scott Seidman 37 mins ago"  Scott . Memorex/Burroughs/Unisys designed a linear HDD in the early 80's in Santa Clara. They wasted about 200 Million$ on it before  it was scrapped. I started work for Burroughs andmy first job was to evaluate and reverse engineer every competitor (OEM) HDD. No one used Linear Servos' after the Quail which was my employer's  last attempt.

Comment: In today's currency , thats about $800m R&D loss  .. Our factory in Winnipeg built the conveyorized Class 100 clean room to build them with special servo writers.    . . . I knew from the start it would fail for many reasons . Linear being one of them. I became the Test Engineering Mgr. after 3 yrs

Comment: My former Burroughs EE colleagues designed the world's fastest linear servo disk drive in the 70's called the 207. The embedded servo design is very similar to what is used today in all rotary HDD's Seagate

Comment: Fine.  None of this has anything to do with a model aircraft servo, other than the presence of a servo amplifier. How would you feel if the OP went out and called the model aircraft servo a voice coil?  This would be an understandable outcome given your answer.

Comment: Voice coils can, of course be servoed.  This does not make a servo motor a voice coil.

Comment: ok you may stick to your old Wikipedia definition.  I gave a general solution and gave examples to support my claim.   How have you helped?  I expect some to be stubborn and disagree due to context.. again this is false "l linear motors, such as those used to move the heads inside hard disk drive" and has not been true since the 80's and museums

Comment: This one is also rotary, but unlike HDD design due to geometry..  Everything in my answer is directed to understanding and solving this acoustic problem, whereas your contribution is about semantics and your obsolete myopic definitions.  This is not personal. Just technically misdirected by your comments.  Focus on the noise problem.

Comment: You might think about defining mmf

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 now that is interesting! Seems like it works with 90 degrees of motion and would be silent as it is just something floating on a track that is pushed and pulled by magnetic forces? Wonder also if this would be available to the consumer? Thanks for recommending

Comment: I cant recommend anything yet until you show a video of problem with sound and budget for a solution